# python glob.glob() regex multi files in different dir

Tags: python, regex, glob

I am trying to use glob.glob() to get a list of files that comes from different directories with two kinds of suffix.

For example, the files i am going to read are

> /ABC/DEF/HIJ/*.{data,index}

and

> /ABC/LMN/HIJ[0-3]/*.{data,index}

I was asked to do it with only a **single** glob.glob() call. 
How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a list comprehension (if this fits your single call criteria),

```
files_wanted = ['/ABC/DEF/HIJ/*.data', '/ABC/DEF/HIJ/*.index', '/ABC/LMN/HIJ[0-3]/*.data', '/ABC/LMN/HIJ[0-3]/*.index'] #List containing your regular expressions.

files_list = [glob.glob(re) for re in files_wanted] #List comprehension.
```

Hope this works for you!